# Is there a way to browse Scabard's characters, irrespective of their campaign?

Tags: tools, scabard

I've noticed that a nice resource to get inspirations is [Scabard](http://www.scabard.com/campaign). However it is apparently browsable only on a Campaign level, with all the Campaign's assets mixed up (characters+cities+random stuff).

Is there a way to browse only a specific category? (i.e. only the characters, or only the cities, for instance)

Even better if I could browse *all* characters, irrespective of their campaign, but even an in-campaign sorting would be good.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Go to the [Query Category](http://www.scabard.com/pbs/page/main/QueryCategory) page on Scabard.

Returns pages across all campaigns that have that category, sorted by campaign score.

**Example: Searching for 'City' pages:**

1. Pick "Place Category" on the selector
2. Enter "City"
3. Click "Search"

[image: Searching for City]

**Full disclosure:** I am the developer of Scabard and created this page in response to this question.

Update 3/21/21: Greatly sped up query and improved aesthetics.

Comment: Wow, you're great! Is there a list of all available categories somewhere?

Comment: @Loharis - try http://www.scabard.com/campaign/121/category. It's paginated, so won't place a big burden on the server.

Comment: @Loharis - I was wondering if you have a campaign of your own on Scabard or whether you just use it for inspiration.  If you have a campaign, what is the name of it?

Comment: Currently I'm just using as a **very** vague inspiration: basically I look at a character, and I re-create a new character using a few aspects of that one as a source. I considered using it to build my campaign, but currently I opted for using a wiki instead – I don't rule out switching to it in future, though currently I'm a bit unaware of its pros and cons.